# Ambiguous line from Browning's My Last Duchess

Tags: phrases, literature

> A heart – how shall I say? – too soon made glad,
>
> Too easily impressed: she liked whate’er
>
> She looked on, and her looks went everywhere.
>
> Sir, ‘twas all one! **My favor at her breast,**
>
> The dropping of the daylight in the West,
>
> The bough of cherries some officious fool
>
> Broke in the orchard for her, the white mule
>
> She rode with round the terrace – all and each
>
> Would draw from her alike the approving speech.

What does the phrase *My favor at her breast* mean in the context of this poem?
I am not sure about how it should be interpreted.

Comment: Have you looked up 'favor', William? 'At her breast' speaks of intimacy (at least in spatial terms), loyalty, biddableness, devotion (on the part of the writer).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Makes sense.

Comment: My English professor is inclined to believe Browning is referring to a necklace, I was hoping someone would maybe mention that (it seems to be a popular perspective) and provide some reasoning.

Comment: I too suspect it refers to some decorative item pinned to her clothes. I'm sure I've read in period fiction of a 'wedding favour' as a knot of white ribbon worn on a gentleman guest's lapel, but online searching finds only references to small gifts given to guests.

Comment: A "favor" was just a piece of cloth, like a handkerchief or a scarf, that was usually given by a lady to her champion in the age of chivalry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [literature.se] tagged "poetry".

Comment: @CJDennis Is the [tag:literature] tag on this site defunct?

Comment: Good point. I should ask a question on Meta about it. If the meaning is open to interpretation (as a lot of poetry is) then it would be off topic here. Is there is a single unambiguous meaning, then it would be on topic here. The comments indicated it was open to interpretation. Note that there were already close votes other than my own here.

Comment: @CJDennis Yes, you probably should take it up at meta. BTW I faced this same kind of problem yesterday (albeit at space.se) where a question had more relevance to a different site but also had a fitting tag on space.se.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For favour(n.) OED gives

> 7.a. (concrete of 1.) Something given as a mark of favour; esp. a gift such as a knot of ribbons, a glove, etc., given to a lover, or in mediæval chivalry by a lady to her knight, to be worn conspicuously as a token of affection.
>   1592   Greenes Groats-worth of Witte sig. C3v   She..returnd him a silke Riband for a fauour tyde with a true loues knot.
>
> 1598   W. Shakespeare Love's Labour's Lost v. ii. 130 + 1   Holde Rosaline, this Fauour thou shalt weare.
>   :1712   Spectator No. 436. ⁋6   That custom of wearing a mistress's favour on such occasions [fencing contests] of old.

And even manages to quote your example as their example:

> 1842   R. Browning My Last Duchess   My favour at her breast.

Whereas originally, favo(u)rs were rarely of any great monetary value - their purpose was simply to be visible on one occasion - usually a on a knight in a fight, This is a favor that the Duke has given to his wife. I suspect that this therefore is not a "real chivalric favor" but more a "love token.

As far as I am aware, men did not give out favours (in the "knightly" sense) to women.

If you look at https://www.medievalists.net/2016/02/five-medieval-love-tokens/, you will see that the favourite candidate is a brooch - displaying love and the wealth of the giver.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dramatic monologue, a poetic form that presupposes supposed listeners. Robert Browning sets in the present poem the Duke of Ferrara to speak about his former wife, the duchess of  Ferrara to a guest. The reference is to painted eyes and expression in a portrait.He
criticizes her for being too easily made happy or impressed. He also claims that she liked everything and everyone she saw whether it was a brooch or present from him that she wore at her chest, the sun setting in the west so on and so forth. Everything would make her happy or she would blush.